# Bottom Sheet Dialog from inside a fragment

Tags: android

i'm currently trying to implement bottomSheetDialog inside my application.
My main activity is composed by a viewpager, a top bar and a bottom navigation bar that i use to switch between fragments. In one of the fragment i'm trying to setup a modal button sheet dialog that have to appear on top of the Main Activity

```
    titleDemo = view.findViewById(R.id.title1);

    titleDemo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(getContext());
            View parentView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
            bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(parentView);
            bottomSheetDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

When i click, the activity behave correctly, fading its colours but nothing shows. For my tests i used a simple layout with some random background color.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/lightCyan">

</LinearLayout>
```

I feel that i'm messing with the views but i can't understand how to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to add these lines

```
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="120dp"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
```

in your `LinearLayout`

Comment: if you are using androidx lib, try replacing the last line with androix